# Best way to connect trading client and trading server

Tags: java, .net, architecture, rabbitmq

I am looking for best way to connect desktop based trading client with Trading server. Latency is most important factor to consider.

We have two option

1 Rest calls: I can call rest service from trading client but i don't think it's good way to do because each call would establish TCP session
2 AMQP(eg:RabbitMQ): We can publish message on RabiitMQ server and server can consume messages from there.

Please suggest which approach is best or is there any other possible approach is well.

Client is in .net and server is java service

Comment: Keeping an open socket should help reduce latency.

Comment: Any recommendation for socket project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Rest call is probably faster than a message queue call in most cases since the message queue will likely involve disk access.

For minimum latency, establish a direct TCP connection and implement your own protocol.